# For loop query in python

Tags: python

```
for i in range(len(X)):
 theta[i]= 0+ (X[i]*0.5)
 break
print(theta)
```

I have `X` as a matrix of random values with 96 rows and 1 column and `T` is another matrix with zeros(96 rows and 1 column).

I need to calculate the following equation with each row value of `X` and need to put the answer in `T`.It's just taking the first value of `X` and putting the same answer in all rows in `T`.

How do I do that? Im beginner in python. TIA

Comment: That code looks okay. What is your question?

Comment: Your loop only sets `theta[0]`; nothing further happens due to the `break`.

Comment: @BlackBear it doesn't look ok, they `break` immediately

Comment: remove the `break` from code and it should work.

Comment: How to take each row value from X(1st to 96th), calculate with equation and put the answer in respective row positions in T?

Comment: If you used numpy, it would simply be `T = X / 0.5`

Answer (score 0):

The break statement inside the for loop will break out of the loop in the first iteration. So, remaining values don't get calculated. Remove the break and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `break` inside your loop. The `break` keyword tells Python to exit the loop as soon as it reaches it. You want the loop to iterate over all values.

```
for i in range(len(X)):
 theta[i]= 0+ (X[i]*0.5)
print(theta)
```